# How to register UDID?

Tags: ios, udid

How do I register UDID with Apple, programmatically, online ?
I don't even know what to ask at the present moment, just need some directions.

Is there an api for it ? What I will need to know to do that from my website for example

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode 5, open the Organizer, select your device and click Add to Member Center. Xcode will handle everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

**1.** Login to https://developer.apple.com/

**2.** Go to the **Member Center**

**3.** Go to the **iOS Provisioning Portal**

**4.** Choose **Devices** on the left navigation.

**5.** Choose **Add Devices**

**6.** Enter a name for the device, and the `UDID`.

You can also register multiple devices:

[image]

**Option 2**

**1.** Plug in your device to your Mac.

**2.** Open Xcode's **Organizer**

**3.** Select your device in the left panel.

**4.** Tap **Use for Development**

Comment: no, what I mean is how do I do it programmatically? Is there an api for it ? What I will need to know to do that from my website for example

Comment: You can load a list with UDIDs. If you go to the Add Devices section there is an option of loading a list with UDIDs of your iDevices. As far as I know, there is no API for it.